# Path finding on a 2d plataformer game. Making enemies jump

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, unity3d-2dtools

I am working 2D Platform running game and I am stuck at this issue, i cant figure it out how to make my enemies jump through platforms as they follow the player. I used A* path finding with a Grid graph for my flying enemy and it works just fine. But with the ground troops i don't know what to do. Any recommendations where to start and what to study? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Place a Trigger (Collider) attached with the Platform at the point where you want your enemy to Act (Jump in your case). and Attach a script to your Enemy to Handle its actions whenever it enters that trigger. you can make it Jump/Fly or whatever you want to. Thumb up if its helpful :)